# Не записывается в БД значение радиокнопки

Tags: jquery, php

POST-запросом данные отправляются обработчику

```
<script>
function setup <? echo$user['id']; ?> () {
    $.post("pages/setup.php", {
        login_user: $("#login_user").val(),
        email_user: $("#email_user").val(),
        telefon_user: $("#telefon_user").val(),
        pass: $("#pass").val(),
        password: $("#password").val(),
        password2: $("#password2").val(),
        money_account_mode: $("#money_account_mode input:radio").val(),
        wmr_user: $("#wmr_user").val(),
        wmz_user: $("#wmz_user").val(),
        qiwi_user: $("#qiwi_user").val(),
        bik_user: $("#bik_user").val(),
        namebank_user: $("#namebank_user").val(),
        fio_user: $("#fio_user").val(),
        karta_user: $("#karta_user").val()
    },

    function (data) {
        if (data != "ok") {
            $("#error_error").html("<div class=\"alert alert-error\"><a class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" href=\"#\">×</a>" + data + "</div>");
        } else {
            $("#setup_forma").hide();
            $("#error_error").html("<div class=\"alert alert-info\">Настройки успешно изменены!</div>");
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

В БД не записывается значение радиокнопок

```
echo '<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="money_account_mode" id="money_account_mode"
        value="мобильный телефон" class="registration_form-check registration_form-check-first"
        checked />Мобильного телефона</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="money_account_mode" id="money_account_mode"
        value="qiwi" class="registration_form-check" />qiwi</label>
</div>';
```

---

Ошибка у нас здесь

---

```
money_account_mode: $("#money_account_mode input:radio").val()
```

Comment: никого не смущает, что в кое присутствует как минимум два элемента с одинаковым id? и конкретизируйте пожалуйста суть ошибки, не записывается в базу или отправляются не те значения?

Comment: Из-за того что 2 ид и не работает?
Как-то не обратил внимания)))

Comment: если в коде присутствуют одинаковые id тогда js при выборке использует всегда только первый

Comment: @vitagame, 
> Как-то не обратил внимания

странно как-то... Что бы было, если бы люди не обращали внимание на то, что блезнящек тоже назвали одинаковыми именнами. ))

Comment: В одно поле таблицы нужно записать одно из выбранных значений.